# Глобальный метод в WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, form

Как мне инициализировать глобальный метод в приложении WPF. Наподобие program.cs в Windows Form. Разъясню... У меня есть метод проверки и подключения к базе данных, который возвращает мне sqlConnection, для дальнейшего использования во всем приложении, в любой форме. В Windows Form приложении, я этот метод могу прописать в файле program.cs в методе main. Как мне тоже самое реализовать в приложении WPF?

Comment: Лучше бы метод обернуть в класс и передавать куда нужно объект класса.

Comment: В App.xaml.cs в конструкторе или методе Startup

Comment: В App.xaml.cs в методе Main я вызывал метод, но форма после этого не появляется

Comment: @aprellskiy: Вы добавили ещё один метод `Main` o_O?

Comment: Вам нужно продвинуться дальше в ваших устремлениях. Надо создать отдельный класс, который будет отвечать за всю работу с БД; все запросы к БД, все обновления данных в БД должен выполнять это класс. Не надо плодить лапша-код, когда всю работу с БД производят в обработчиках событий нажатия на кнопки. Экземпляр этого класса можно подгружать на событие Loaded у формы.

Comment: Если вы создали ещё один метод Main, то надо в настройках проекта выбрать его как стартовый. Но вам придется организовать запуск окна самостоятельно. А вообще в моем комментарии нету ничего по метод Main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мне просто нужно было бы вызывать перед появлением главного окошка метод и получить ссылку на какой-нибудь объект я бы воспользовался статическим методом и вызвал его в конструкторе MainWindow.

```
/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MyClass.MyMethod();
        InitializeComponent();

        if (MyClass.MyResource != null) MessageBox.Show("Ok!");
    }
}
public class MyClass 
{
    public static object MyResource;
    public static void MyMethod() 
    {
        MyResource = new object();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, да и что? Это такой ответ на собственный вопрос?

Comment: возможно я не понял что человек хочет...А кстати что он хочет?